# How to redirect my URLs using htaccess 301 conditional

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need help redirecting my old URL to a new URL.

They URLS are structured as required.

My OLD URL is something like `domain.com/category/123-title-of-article.html`, where `category` is the category name and `123` is the Post ID

The NEW URLs are (and this is how I want them to redirect): `domain.com/article/title-of-article-123/`, where `article` will remain as it is in all URLS, and the post ID will go to end of the URL

How I can achieve this?

Comment: have you made any attempt to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /article/$3-$2/ [R=301,L]
```

It should change `domain.com/category/123-title-of-article.html` to `domain.com/article/title-of-article-123/`

Comment: category is not a fixed slug it is category name however article is going to be a fixed slug

Comment: Thank you very very much it worked you save my night

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?category/(\d+)-(.+)\.html$ /article/$2-$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Also, you already have the rewrite rules to handle your new URL, right?